# An ant colony algorithm for multiple sequence alignment in bioinformatics matlab toolbox

Tags: matlab

is there any matlab toolbox for An ant colony algorithm for multiple sequence alignment in bioinformatics ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be one for termite colonies, but you would have to deal with type conversion :p

Otherwise I would check http://www.mathworks.com/products/
Or more specifically http://www.mathworks.com/products/bioinfo/